# How to access multiple nested variables in Jekyll YAML config

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I'm building a web page using [Poole/Lanyon](https://github.com/poole/lanyon). [A file](https://github.com/poole/lanyon/blob/master/_includes/sidebar.html#L28) uses a multi-level or nested site variable like `{{ site.github.repo }}`.

As a novice in Ruby and YAML, I'm not sure how I should declare this value in `_config.yml`. I tried like this in `_config.yml`:

```
github:
  - repo:  'https://github.com/foo/bar.github.io'
```

It was not working: an empty string is returned when I use `{{ site.github.repo }}`. I'm however able to get `{{ site.github }}` like this:
`{"repo"=>"https://github.com/foo/bar.github.io"}`

In order to use `site.github.repo`, how should I define this variable in the configuration file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `_config.yml`, you've defined `site.github` as a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Lists), and you're trying to access it as an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Associative_arrays), hence the problem.

If you want to access it as an associative array, you'll need to redefine your variable as such:

```
github:
  repo: 'https://github.com/foo/bar.github.io'
```

As of writing this, I don't think that the Wikipedia sections I have linked to are super clear, but you can refer to their [sample document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Sample_document), which I think showcases YAML's possibilities pretty well.